# do product, manager and resume tags have any value on stack overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I saw a question on SO with the product, manager and resume tags. I don't see any of these tags adding anything meaningful and probably should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

They all have legitimate meaning on Stack Overflow, but all of these tags do need to be cleaned up (*not* removed).

- `product` can mean the result of multiplication (which probably doesn't need its own tag), but I noticed it also seems to have a special meaning in the `magento` tag.  Search [`[product]` `[magento]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product+magento)
- "Manager" is often used in object-oriented programming and there's a [Manager design pattern](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/ManagerDesignPattern.htm).
- Resume (not résumé) is often used as in [Suspend and Resume thread (Windows, C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213630/suspend-and-resume-thread-windows-c).

Comment: The first two I can see, but if `resume` is really meant in the context of threading then it's a lousy tag.  `[multithreading]` already tells us everything we need to know about the question's topic; I really doubt that there are any experts specifically on the topic of *resuming* threads (and even if there were, then the appropriate tag would be `[resuming]`, not `[resume]`). That one really smacks of people pasting the question title into the tag box.

Comment: @Aarobot: Yeah, on second thought I agree.  Unfortunately too many people use it when they mean "résumé" so I think it would make a bad synonym.

Comment: my thoughts on the matter: product as in multiplication does not need a tag. product in the context of magento is probably better expressed as magento-product. manager appears to be used for many different things, if we want a tag for the manager design pattern (though I think that might be a bit too specific) then manager-design-pattern would probably be a better name. I would argue that questions to do with résumés are probably better served on programmers.SE ... if it's about résumés for programmers that is.

Comment: @Brian: That all seems reasonable.  I've already cleared out all the résumé questions.  The [resume] tag is now only used on questions like suspend-resume, which I think might be what the tag should be.